# jQuery dropdown menu flickering

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm having an issue with my dropdown menu which utilises the jquery slideDown and slideUp functions.

If you have your mouse over the dropdown UL, if you move it out and back inside while it is still sliding up it starts flickering/flashing, as if it is firing the mouseenter and mouseleave event in rapid quickfire.

I have setup a fiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LxL8Q/3/

In Chrome, it only flickers for a second and then remedies itself, in Firefox however it continues flickering for an indefinite amount of time.

I know there are a number of questions related to flickering jQuery on here, but I was unable to find anything with an answer that could help me.

I did try replacing the entire .each loop with a simple hover function but after doing that my slideup and slidedown animations weren't working.

Comment: Try using the default values of `.stop()` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LxL8Q/4/

Comment: @j08691 This works pretty well, do you know if there is a simple way to get it to slide back down instead of just stopping it while it is partially collapsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(function($){  

var nav = $("#topNav");  

nav.find("li").each(function() {  
if ($(this).find("ul").length > 0) {  

    //show subnav on hover  
    $(this).mouseover(function() {  
        $(this).find("ul").slideDown(300);  
    });  
    //hide submenus on exit  
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {  
        $(this).removeClass('active').find("ul").stop(true).slideUp(300);  
    });  
 }  
});

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: When I do that I just lose the sliding animation completely

Comment: You want it to stop after it slides up or down.

Comment: Oh I see in IE it does not animate

Comment: With this solution I don't get any sliding at all. In firefox too.

Comment: This does the trick now, do you know if there is an easy way to get it to re-open again instead of stopping partially collapsed?

Comment: that should fix your partial collapse problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and have found a solution: add `delay(50)` before `slideUp(300)`. Checkout the new fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LxL8Q/42/